# Is there a classification of local rings with trivial group of units?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Out of curiosity, is there a classification of all local rings with trivial group of units?

I suppose what I'm trying to ask is, if I asked for all local rings $R$ with $R^\times=\{1\}$, what would they be?

Comment: Is it your intention that $-1=1$?  Or do you want to add that as a (possibly different) unit?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In a local ring, the non-units are precisely the maximal ideal, and in particular, are closed under addition.  For any $x \in R$, we have $x + (1-x) = 1$, a unit, and therefore at least one of $x$ and $1-x$ is a unit.  Since 1 is the only unit, it follows that either $x=0$ or $x=1$.  Since $x$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $R$ is the field of 2 elements.